# Detecting which copy of custom class was tapped

Tags: android, view, android-activity, copy, onactivityresult

I have a custom xml view which, when a button is tapped, a duplicate is created into the main view.

```
Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayout newCard = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.vehicle, null);
        cardLayout.addView(newCard);
        final int thisCarId = new Random().nextInt(10000);
    }
});
```

A user can tap the addButton as many times as he/she wants, and I produce a new newCard each time.

Each newCard has an ImageButton, and an EditText; when the ImageButton is tapped, I start a Camera intent with Result:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, thisCarId);
```

Later in this activity class, I anticipate the result of the Camera activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.v("car", "The ID that was returned: " + requestCode);
}
```

My log DOES properly ascertain which instance of newCard, by way of the thisCardId... but how can I tell which newCard was created, so that I can set the ImageButton found in that newCard layout to match the camera photo? Assigning the photo is no problem... just, I don't know which one to assign it, because onActivityResult is out-of-scope, and so far as I can tell, I can't assign an anonymous Override for the activity as a whole...

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you're trying to do but from **"I can't assign an anonymous Override for the activity as a whole..."** do you mean setting an `OnClickListener` to the `Activity`? If so, just have your `Activity` implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface.

Comment: Sorry, words are not my strong point; i meant setting an anonymous onActivityResult dedicated to the instance of the newCard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can do`newCard.setTag(thisCarId)` then loop through the cardLayout children views for the child that has the tag you are looking for. Something like

```
           for(int i = 0; i < cardLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                if((Integer)cardLayout.getChildAt(i).getTag() == cardId){
                    //do something
                }
            }
```

Comment: wow... so much about the language I don't know. I'm going to try this.

Comment: With a lot of child views this would be inefficient. Instead of using `setTag(thisCarId)` it would be better to use `setId(thisCarId)`. Then in `onActivityResult` use `cardLayout.findViewById(requestCode)`.

Comment: OO, i may try that as well, Squonk. However, this did give me the result I needed, except for the fact that Views which did not get a Tag assigned are returned null, so I have to ignore the nulls, and jump out when I'm done.

Comment: @JamesPerih : Actually I just remembered there's a `findViewWithTag(...)` method as well but it's not something I've used often. I don't know which is most efficient but I suspect using the ints as ids rather than as `Object` tags should be quicker.

Comment: Also have to watch out for duplicate random numbers. Might be better off with an incremental counter

Comment: I used Squonk's solution, since the View complexity just got more complex due to client needs (there are now a variable amount of ImageButtons required). However, I can't make the comment the solution, AND Kenny C's solution helped zero things in!